# link sails.io.js in angular2

Tags: node.js, angular, sails.js, sails.io.js

I'm having trouble using sails.io.js with angular2. I use the angular2-sails library.

First I decided to use with a code inside my app.component.ts

```
this._sailsService.connect(this.url);
```

It works but when I launched the app I also have those messages "Socket is trying to reconnect to Sails.." I checked, it's trying to connect to port 4200.

I used sails.io.js with

```
  "scripts": ["sails.io.js"]
```

in angular-cli.json. But I tried something else :

```
 <script src="sails.io.js">          // I also tried src="src/sails.io.js
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
      io.sails.useCORSRouteToGetCookie = false;
      io.sails.url = 'http://localhost:1337';
  </script>
```

in index.html, and my browser returns that it cannot load the script at "http://localhost:4200/sails.io.js" or "http://localhost:4200/src/sails.io.js"

folders :

```
app.js
angular-cli.json
src
-index.html
-sails.io.js
-app
--app.component.ts
```

I don't know why it tries to connect to 4200 when it's called in the angular-cli.json and why it can't access my sails.io.js when called in the index.